# Trying to get this code to work, can't understand where to put the argument in and keep getting errors

Tags: racket

Define the function iota1(n, m) that takes positive integers n, m with n < m as input, and outputs the list (n,n+1,n+2,...,m)

I've tried switching the code around multiple times but cannot seem to get it to function and display a list the right way

```
(define (iota1 n m)
  (if (eq? n 0)
      '()
      (append (iota1 (< n m) (+ n 1)) (list n))))
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a few oddities to the code you provided, which I've formatted for readability:

```lisp
(define (iota1 n m)
  (if (eq? n 0)
      '()
      (append (iota (< n m) (+ n 1))
              (list n))))
```

The first is that the expression `(< n m)` evaluates to a boolean value, depending on whether `n` is less than `m` or not. When you apply `iota` to `(< n m)` in the expression `(iota (< n m) (+ n 1))`, you are giving `iota` a boolean value for its first argument instead of a positive integer.

Secondly, the use of `append` is strange here. When constructing a list in Racket, it's much more common to use the function `cons`, which takes as arguments a value, and a list, and returns a new list with the value added to the front. For example,

```lisp
(append '(3) (append '(4) (append '(5) '()))) ==> '(3 4 5)
(cons 3 (cons 4 (cons 5 '())))                ==> '(3 4 5)
```

It's a good idea to opt for using `cons` instead of `append` because it's simpler, and because it is faster, since `cons` does not traverse the entire list like `append` does.

Since this sounds a bit like a homework problem, I'll leave you with a "code template" to help you find the answer:

```lisp
; n : integer
; m : integer
; return value : list of integers
(define (iota1 n m)
  (if (> n m)                  ; base case; no need to do work when n is greater than m
      ...                      ; value that goes at the end of the list
      (cons ...                ; the value we want to add to the front of the list
            (iota1 ... ...)))) ; the call to iota, generating the rest of the list
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and sorry for the late response but, the only problem I am having is that whenever I put in the second argument("value that goes at the end of the list") it comes back as "expects a real as 2nd argument, given (cons 3 '())", I have the rest of the program complete just not that part, what does it mean by looking for a real argument? I tried googling it but came up with nothing. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: It's referring to the contract `real?`, which returns true when given a real number. See https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/number-types.html?q=real#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._real~3f%29%29 for more information

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the racket world, my version is here:

```
#lang racket

(define (iota1 n m)
  (let loop ([loop_n n]
             [result_list '()])
    (if (<= loop_n m)
        (loop
         (add1 loop_n)
         (cons loop_n result_list))
        (reverse result_list))))
```